# actix minimal channel example

Tags: rust, channel, actix-web

I'm trying to replicate a simple benchmark for async-channel in actix-web. However, actix seems never to call the `recv` function. How can this be?

Does the `await` in the sending thread never cause tokio to yield to the other thread? I thought `await` yielded the current context?

```rust
#[actix_web::main]
async fn main() {
    let (s, r) = async_channel::unbounded();

    let t1 = tokio::spawn(async move {
        let mut now = chrono::Utc::now();
        while let Ok(x) = r.recv().await {
            if x % 1 == 0 {
                let next_now = chrono::Utc::now();
                println!("{} {:?}", x, next_now - now);
                now = next_now;
            }
        }
    });

    let t2 = tokio::spawn(async move {
        for i in 1.. {
            s.send(i).await.unwrap();
        }
    });

    join!(t1, t2).await;
}
```

I tried taking each of the code blocks outside the spawn calls, and replacing "join!" with select and other futures calls (also getting rid of it entirely).

I'm also trying to figure out whether it's OK to use actix-web with tokio (specifically, tokio::spawn within actix-web and actix::rt::spawn within tokio::main).

Comment: While actix does use tokio underneath, it's probably best to call the actix-provided methods when using actix just to ensure everything plays nicely together. One immediately obvious difference is that `actix_rt::spawn` calls `tokio::task::spawn_local`, which is not entirely the same as `tokio::spawn`.

Comment: I want to use tokio spawn because it can create separate threads: all spawns in actix are the same thread

Comment: Is `#[actix_web::main]` actually a multi-threaded runtime? Otherwise, `tokio::spawn` will not actually run on a different thread.

Comment: I don't know: that's a good question. Is it?

Comment: @Test I don't think so :D Why do you need a multi-threaded runtime?

Comment: Performance--handling many requests at the same time

Comment: I guess read https://actix.rs/docs/server/ - Multi-Threading. And this maybe: https://github.com/actix/actix-web/discussions/1747

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```rust
for i in 1.. {
    s.send(i).await.unwrap();
}
```

This loop never yields. Yes, there is an `await` in there, but `send()` only actually pauses if the channel is full. As you created an `unbounded()` channel, it will run out of memory before it is considered full. And without yielding, the other task will never be executed.

Try changing your channel to a `bounded` one, or try to `sleep` in the loop:

```rust
let t2 = tokio::spawn(async move {
    for i in 1.. {
        s.send(i).await.unwrap();
        tokio::time::sleep(Duration::from_millis(500)).await;
    }
});
```

If I had to choose, I'd make the channel bounded. Having an infinite generator combined with an unbounded channel is always a bad idea.